# Remove attributes using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to create a code snippet to remove all `style` attributes regardless of tag using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://HtmlAgilityPack.codeplex.com).

Here's my code:

```
var elements = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*");

if (elements!=null)
{
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        element.Attributes.Remove("style");
    }
}
```

However, I'm not getting it to stick? If I look at the `element` object immediately after `Remove("style")`. I can see that the style attribute *has been removed*, but it still appears in the `DocumentNode` object. :/

I'm feeling a bit stupid, but it seems off to me? Anyone done this using HtmlAgilityPack? Thanks!

**Update**

I changed my code to the following, and it works properly:

```
public static void RemoveStyleAttributes(this HtmlDocument html)
{
   var elementsWithStyleAttribute = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@style");

   if (elementsWithStyleAttribute!=null)
   {
      foreach (var element in elementsWithStyleAttribute)
      {
         element.Attributes["style"].Remove();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a reproduction code? because I have tested this html `<html style='style1'><body style='style2'></body></html>` and it works

Comment: Do you use InnerHtml property? At the time of writing this it has a bug, use WriteContentTo method instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be correct - it removes the attributes. The thing is, `DocumentNode .InnerHtml`(I assume you monitored this property) is a complex property, maybe it get updated after some unknown circumstances and you actually shouldn't use this property to get the document as a string. Instead of it `HtmlDocument.Save` method for this:

```
string result = null;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    htmlDoc.Save(writer);
    result = writer.ToString();
}
```

now `result` variable holds the string representation of your document.

One more thing: your code may be improved  by changing your expression to `"//*[@style]"` which gets you only elements with `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Yeah, I had changed my code to the following to make it "stick":

'public static void RemoveStyleAttributes(this HtmlDocument html)
        {
            var elementsWithStyleAttribute = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@style");

            if (elementsWithStyleAttribute!=null)
            {
                foreach (var element in elementsWithStyleAttribute)
                {
                    element.Attributes["style"].Remove();
                }
            }
        }'

Not sure why my original code didn't work, but I think you're right in your guess. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, code formatting in comments isn't great. :) Updated my question with the modified code snippet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a very simple solution

VB.net

```
element.Attributes.Remove(element.Attributes("style"))
```

c#

```
element.Attributes.Remove(element.Attributes["style"])
```

Comment: Thanks, one correction: element.Attributes("style") should be element.Attributes["style"]

Comment: You are right cause i don't make it clear : my code is for vb.net