# Remove style from HTML Tags using Regex C#

Tags: c#, html

I want to remove style from HTML Tags using C#. It should return only HTML Simple Tags.
For i.e.
if `String = <p style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px;">Hello</p>`
Then it should return `String = <p>Hello</p>`

Like that for all HTML Tags, `<strong></string>, <b></b>` etc. etc.
Please help me for this.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850718/remove-attributes-using-htmlagilitypack

Comment: Are you (accidentally) missing the closing quote?

Comment: @RobP., yes, sorry. Updated post.

Comment: Probably because this question has been asked a million times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, as others suggest, an approach using a proper HTML parser is [much better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Either use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

If you really want a regex solution, here it is:

Replace this pattern: `(<.+?)\s+style\s*=\s*(["']).*?\2(.*?>)`
With: `$1$3`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qJ1vM1/1

---

To remove multiple attributes, since you're using .NET, this should work:

Replace `(?<=<[^<>]+)\s+(?:style|class)\s*=\s*(["']).*?\1`
With an empty string

Comment: Regex is working fine. But in code, It is showing error `unrecognized escape sequence` because of " in string. What should i do ??? I am using it as `@"(<.+?)\s+style\s*=\s*(["']).*?\2(.*?>)", "")`

Comment: @CSAT Read about c# strings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Please note that it is not working for other tags like '<ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
<strong style="font:bold">Endoderm</strong>' What to do for this ?

Comment: And I also want to remove `class` so will i make to another regex as same like style ?

Comment: @CSAT It's working for me, so please show how you used it so I can tell you what's wrong. If you also want to remove `class`, see my edit.

Comment: works perfect, but can you please update the code so that it also remove `data-xxx` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

As others said, You can use HTML Agility pack, which has this nice tool: [HTML Agility Pack test](https://htmlxpathtestbed.codeplex.com/) which shows you what you're doing.

Other than that, it's regex, which is not recommended with HTML usually, or simply running on your code with a loop on all chars. If it starts with `<` read until whitespace, and then remove all the chars up until `>`. That should take care of most basic cases, but you'll have to test it.

Here's a little snippet that will do it:

```
void Main()
{
    // your input
    String input = @"<p style=""margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px;"">Hello</p>";
    // temp variables
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool inside = false;
    bool delete = false;
    // analyze string
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // Special case, start bracket
        if (input[i].Equals('<')) { 
            inside = true;
            delete = false;
        }
        // special case, close bracket
        else if (input[i].Equals('>')) {
            inside = false;
            delete = false;
        }
        // other letters
        else if (inside) {
            // Once you have a space, ignore the rest until closing bracket
            if (input[i].Equals(' '))
                delete = true;
        }   
        // add if needed
        if (!delete)
                sb.Append(input[i]);
    }
    var result = sb.ToString(); // -> holds: "<p>Hello</p>"
}
```

Comment: this fails if like this </ p>

Comment: this also fails if there are <> inside e.g. <math>K_B \cap\left \{ |k| < \beta\right \} </math>

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG yep. it will .

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the below code to remove inline styles, class, images and comments from an Outlook message prior to saving it into database:

```
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<style.+?</style>)|(<script.+?</script>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<img.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<o:.+?</o:.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "<!--.+?-->", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "class=.+?>", ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "class=.+?\s", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Your regex pattern of `class=.+?>` removes everything between `class=` and the next `>` which is more than what you want. `class=.+?\"` is probably what you were after.

Comment: he should use `class=".+?"` or `class='.+?'` instead of  `class=.+?>`

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are fine but it can also be done simply by using this method:
"Your HTML String".replace("style", "data-tags");
You can also replace "class" the same way.

Answer (score -1):

```
   source = Regex.Replace(source, "(<style.+?</style>)|(<script.+?</script>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
   source = Regex.Replace(source, "(<img.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
   source = Regex.Replace(source, "(<o:.+?</o:.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
   source = Regex.Replace(source, "<!--.+?-->", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
   source = Regex.Replace(source, "class=.+?>", ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
   source = Regex.Replace(source.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"), "<[^(a|img|b|i|u|ul|ol|li)][^>]*>", " ");
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.