# C# Regex remove href

Tags: c#, regex

So basically I want to remove `href` ie.:

```
<td class="name"><a href="/leagues/euw/633">Apdo Dog2</a></td>
```

So I just want the `Apdo Dog2` part of the text. Any idea?

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SITE");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string final_response = stream.ReadToEnd();

    Regex r = new Regex(@"\<[^\>]+\>(.[^\<]+)</[^\>]+\>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match m = r.Match(final_response);

    richTextBox1.Text = m.Value;
```

Comment: You should really use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). There's a huge selection of HTML that will break plain regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Ideas? Yes, you should use a parser such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract these values.

You don't need to escape the bracket characters, these characters have no special meaning. But, the main problem is the dot `.` **remove** it. And then refer to the group using **Match.**[Groups Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) to access your match result.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>");
Match m = r.Match(final_response);
richTextBox1.Text = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

**Note**: The dot `.` is removed and you are using negated classes, so you can remove the dotall modifier.

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/IKoLix)

Comment: Thats good, what should I add if I want more than one line as output?

Comment: Use Regex.Matches method.

Comment: I tried with it and got this as output: http://i.imgur.com/wsho8Yo.png Do you know why? kinda strange

Comment: If you just want the content values, try `Regex r = new Regex(@"<a[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jF9fQ0/1)**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25306943/1698987) and do something similar I guess.

The only difference is that you'll delete/remove all the stuff including the brackets.

Other than that, keep in mind that the general consensus is to not mix RexEx with HTML :)

This should work :

```
void Main()
{
    // your input
    String input = @@"<td class=""name""><a href=""/leagues/euw/633"">Apdo Dog2</a></td>";
    // temp variables
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool inside = false;
    bool delete = false;
    // analyze string
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // Special case, start bracket
        if (input[i].Equals('<')) { 
            inside = true;

        }
        // special case, close bracket
        else if (input[i].Equals('>')) {
            inside = false;
            continue;
        }

        // add if needed
        if (!inside)
                sb.Append(input[i]);
    }
    var result = sb.ToString(); // -> holds: "Apdo Dog2"
}
```

Comment: For what should this work? This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: For: `<td class="name"><a href="/leagues/euw/633">Apdo Dog2</a></td>`, it'll give you `Apdo Dog2`